# Fix hover "ri" in Janus, Vim setup?

Tags: vim, janus, ri

I have installed [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) to improve my vim. All works fine, except for the Ri documentation, that opens on hovering a keyword. On my installation it shows the output of "ri --help" instead of the documentation of the keyword.

I have found a [way to disable it](https://groups.google.com/group/vim_mac/browse_thread/thread/b60d3fc3a9a6f376/f42ee896ed8c700a?show_docid=f42ee896ed8c700a), but I'd rather just fix it. I am using gvim on Ubuntu 11.10.

What is the name of the plugin or script that offers these tooltips?

Could it have anything to do with RVM being active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bug in the ruby.vim plugin. That triggers ri with a wrong argument.

There is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=342) for this.

Solving is easy: edit file `.../ftplugin/ruby.vim` and change line `194`: the -f argument should not be `simple`, but either `bs` or `ansi`. I had success with `bs`.

Answer (score 1):

Does any of these shortcuts (from [ri's homepage](http://danielchoi.com/software/ri_vim.html)) work, especially the last two?

- `,r` opens the search/autocomplete window, and will use a horizontal split to display matching documentation
- `,R` opens the search/autocomplete window, and will use a vertical split to display matching documentatoin
- `,K` opens the search/autocomplete window and prefills it with the keyword under the cursor
- `K` is automatically remapped to use ri.vim if the current buffer is a *.rb file

Comment: Yes. The last two give me ri output. The first two appear to do nothing.